# Why does Select return a boolean?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm working with Entity Framework 6 in MVC 5.

I have the following method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateDetails(ApplicationUser applicationUser)
{
    var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var user = context.Users.Select(x => x.UserName == applicationUser.UserName).FirstOrDefault();

//etc etc
}
```

Users is an `IDbSet<ApplicationUser>`.

Why am I getting a bool back from the Select method?

My expectation would be to get an `ApplicationUser` object back. Why isn't this the case?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks guys, will accept when I can, I'm an idiot. Thanks again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) projects an element of a sequence. Since `x.UserName == applicationUser.UserName` returns a `bool`, the result of the method will be a boolean.

What you want requires the [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. This filters the sequence based on the specified predicate:

```
var user = context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == applicationUser.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == applicationUser.UserName);
```

This is possible, since [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload of `FirstOrDefault()` takes a filter predicate as second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your select is returning an object that is the result of the comparison.

Change to:

```
var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == applicationUser.UserName);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are SELECTing a boolean.

Since there is no requirement specified, I am guessing your requirement from your attempted code.

use the below line.

```
var user=context.Users.Where(user=>user.UserName==applicationUser.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Select` literally selects something inside the arguments. So, if you have an expression that returns a `bool`, `Select` will return `bool`.